# Why do I get "use a newer compileSdk of at least 34" error in Android studio?

Tags: android, logcat

" "app is currently compiled against android-33. Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk of at least 34, for example 34. Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which allows newer APIs to be""

I wanted to get a log of methods  that I ran on virtual phone.

Comment: this is not an error

Comment: Have you considered listening to what the error says and using `compileSdk 34`?

Answer (score 2):

I have changed compileSdk and targetSdk version from 33 to 34 in app level gradle file.

```
android {
namespace = "com.undivided.todo"
compileSdk = 34
        
defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.undivided.todo"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    // ...
}
```

You can use the `Log.d()` or other log methods to print information to the Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sdk version 33 then change the material library version in your app level gradle file.

```
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
```

Changed version to 1.9.0

```
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
```

Because Material 1.10.0 supports only after sdk level 34 or newer.